# -bash: [: missing `]' whenever I start the terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

For some reason, I get this message

***-bash: [: missing `]'***

when I open a new terminal, does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: @Matteo GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check all the scripts that are started by login

- `.profile`
- `.bashrc`
- `.bash_profile`

If other users are affected then also

- `/etc/profile`
- `/etc/bashrc`

In one of them there is a statement calling `test` with `[` without a closing bracket `]`. Search for all `[` and check if they are properly closed.

Comment: thank you very much :) I didn't knew those things are called when you go start bash :)